# Evaluating expression in loop condition

Tags: python

For some ***n***, lets define result in the following way:

```
result = [x for x in [i for i in range(0, n)]]
```

Does python evaluate the inner list each time? Or does it evaluate it only the first time?
Because this is the difference between run time of ***O(n)*** or ***O(n^2)***.
For example:

```
result = [x for x in func()]
```

Does python call the function ***func*** each iteration?

This might be a duplicate, I just couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Um, each iterable in your first expression is iterated once. First the `range` is iterated on to build the inner list, then the inner list is iterated (once) to build the outer list (which is identical to the inner list, and to the `range`, making all the iterating pretty silly).

Comment: Yea it's just an example. So the function will be called only once? This make it O(n)?

Comment: It's exactly the same as a normal `for` loop, so just like `for x in func(): do_whatever()`, the `func` function will be called just once. The time compexity is `O(n)` plus the time complexity of `func` (which in big-O notation generally means whichever is worse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why wouldn't you try that yourself?

```
def foo():
    print('foo called')
    return range(5)


result = [x for x in [i for i in foo()]]
print(result)
>>  foo called
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

`foo` is obviously being called once.

Comment: Oh should've thought of that! Thank you!